# How to set a JTable row with checkbox to checked (or true)?

Tags: java

Given a string for example which consist of "1001011", how do I make the JTable row with checkbox to checked if the character is 1 or unchecked if 0, iteratively

Comment: can you please explain by example ? so that we can understood more clearly your requirement?

Comment: all I want was the code to check the checkbox in a JTable

Comment: kindly refer my anwer.

Comment: Each column you want represented as a check box will need to return Boolean.class from the getColumnClass method of the TableModel. You will then need to return true or false from getValueAt method of the TableModel for each column represented by the check boxes according to your data's requirements. If isCellEditable of the TableModel returns true for the columns, you'll need to override the setValueAt method and update your data model accordingly when the state of the column is changed.

Comment: Personally, it use String#charAt if you don't need an editable table, otherwise, I'd break the String down into a char array so you could update it

Comment: You should start by having a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)